# Google chart height issue

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I've got strange problem while I'm trying to use google charts. Chart's height is changing when I am using diffrent data sets within same boundary.

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function drawVisualization() {
    var jsonDataSet = [["27-12-2013",4.5],["28-12-2013",4.5],["29-12-2013",4.5],["30-12-2013",4.5],["31-12-2013",4.5],["01-01-2014",4.5],["02-01-2014",4.5]];

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Credibility');
    data.addRows(jsonDataSet);

    // Set chart options
    var chartOptions  = {
      chartArea: {
        height: 220,
        width: 340,
        left: 20,
        top: 5
      },
      legend: 'none',
      titlePosition: 'none',
      width: 370,
      height: 280,
      vAxis: {
        format: '0',
        ticks: [0,1,2,3,4,5],
        viewWindowMode: 'maximized'
      },
      hAxis: {
        slantedText: true,
        slantedTextAngle: 40,
        viewWindowMode: 'maximized'
      }
    };

    var credibilityChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));

    // Draw chart, passing in some options.
    credibilityChart.draw(data, chartOptions);
  }

  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
</script>
```

This is the output of the script:

http://jsbin.com/edaKuce/3/edit?js,output

And this is the output of the same script with different data set:

var jsonDataSet = [["28-12-2013",4],["28-12-2013",2.1],["29-12-2013",2.2],["30-12-2013",2.4],["31-12-2013",3.9],["01-01-2014",3.1],["02-01-2014",4]];

http://jsbin.com/edaKuce/6/edit?js,output

Any suggestions?

Comment: That is incredibly odd. If all the numbers are the same, it displays with the odd axis, but if you change any number by even .001 it displays correctly. My guess is that it is a bug of some form and should be reported on [the visualization api google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've found a bug, which you can report [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list).  In the meantime, you can work around this by setting the `vAxis.maxValue` option:

```
vAxis: {
    format: '0',
    ticks: [0,1,2,3,4,5],
    viewWindowMode: 'maximized', // this will have no effect on this chart, incidentally
    maxValue: 5
}
```

Comment: Many thanks in advance, adding maxValue fixed the issue for now. 
I have also created a bug report as you suggested: 
https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1437